# Wordpress single.php get_header not working

Tags: php, theme-development

I'm creating a custom Wordpress Theme and I can't seem to get the single.php template to work. Below is the code I have written. The file of index.php reads up but the single.php doesn't. Any Ideas why it isn't?

I'm (locally) building a custom theme.

So far I have:

- index.php
- single.php

[image: themes]

**single.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="post-entry">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Sidebar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="wp-content/themes/oxbir/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="wp-content/themes/oxbir/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: What is the page that you are using to test the `single.php` template with? I notice you hardcoded the CSS files into the header, this is _highly_ unusual, is there a reason you didn't enqueue via `wp_enqueue_style`? Is this a child theme? What is the difference between `index.php ` and `single.php`?

Comment: In the index.php file, it calls the CSS, and in the single.php file, it does not call the CSS.

Comment: but if both files call `get_header()` and there is only 1 `header.php` why would they be different? I notice you ignored the other questions I asked in my comment, do you have answers for those? How does `index.php` call the CSS? Be very descriptive and ensure your question contains everything needed to answer it

Comment: It’s because your CSS URLs are relative. Look in the dev tools no you’ll see it’s trying to load them from a non-existent directory. You should enqueue CSS properly: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/